# Redirect based on referrer sends a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, wordpress, http-headers

I got this code that for some reason is not fully working, although it seems im on the right direction, and i have a guess on why is it not working, eventhough i dont know how to fix.

The ide is so if the HTTP_REFERER = a web containing the word example, and you are not loged it, then redirect you to mysite.com/login

```
add_action( 'init', 'example_redirect');
function metorik_redirect() {
if (!is_user_logged_in() && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "example")){
        wp_redirect( site_url('/login/') ); 
        exit; 
    }   
}
```

The rule above seems to be triggering when conditions are met, but then it returns ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

My guess is that it keeps finding the referer to be example everytime it loops through that function and then it never gets out of it. As stated, is just a guess.

***UPDATE 1:***
I have tried with this other code i found in here stackoverflow, with same results:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_if_example');
function redirect_if_example(){
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && coming_from_example(wp_get_referer()) ){
         wp_safe_redirect( "/login/" );
         exit;
     } else{
          wp_safe_redirect( get_home_url() );
          exit;
     }
}

function coming_from_example($url_string){
   if ($url_string){
      $url = parse_url($url_string);
      return strpos($url['host'], 'example.com');
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}
```

Thanks
Kind regards

Comment: Can You show example_redirect function? As Your init action isn't pointing to function You posted "metorik_redirect" but to "example_redirect"

Comment: To be honest with you, no idea what that init thing is or what it does. I mean i do not code myself, so it seems that i copied and ammend code from a different question in stackoverflow to try to make it do what i need it to do, but clearly I have done something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to redirect in correct hook and use correct strpos function like this: (this code should be in your functions.php file)

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'example_redirect');
function example_redirect() {
if (!is_user_logged_in() && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], "example") !== false){
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); 
        exit; 
    }   
}
```

Also please make sure you are actually comming from website which has `example` string in it.

Comment: Hey man! you are an absolute star, I just made a small ammend to your code, as our login page is hidden behind a different URL than the normal wp_login_url, but i will leave your answer as correct, as I beleive it will be the best for 99% of the people. Thanks so much for your help, and i will read the code and try to understand it, so i can some day make small pieces of code myself.